# Converting STRING to DATE in BigQuery

Tags: string, date, casting, google-bigquery, case

I have a column called order_date in a table in BigQuery and it is of the data type STRING. It has two types of values 10/2/2020 and 2020-10-02. PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', order_date) converts 10/2/2020 to DATE and CAST(order_date as DATE) converts 2020-10-02 to DATE. I wrote the CASE statement below to handle both of the cases but it is erroring out.

```
CASE 
WHEN FORMAT(order_date) ='%m/%d/%Y'THEN PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y',order_date)
ELSE CAST (order_date AS DATE) END AS order_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex pattern to assert the `%m/%d/%Y` variant:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(order_date, r"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$")
         THEN PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', order_date)
         ELSE CAST(order_date AS DATE) END AS order_date
FROM yourTable;
```